# How to properly execute javascript against a DOM element upon ng-show?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

There's a TLDR at the bottom. Otherwise here's the long-winded explanation.

I have a sort of a form, a series of various inputs that is divided into "pages" by using ng-show.

What I want is when ng-show activates and shows a new "page" and hides the old, then to execute javascript to add a class, focus, then find the input and focus on that. Essentially highlighting the next thing the user needs to do on this new page and focusing for quick input.

I've been trying to get a $watch to work but I feel like this might be over-complicating something that might have an easier alternative nor can I get it working properly.

The pages each have several divs that are questions, directions, or input elements. But when a page becomes visible, there would be one div in particular that I would highlight (see myFocusDirective placement), because some of the divs aren't actionable by the user. Example of pages:

```
<div id="page1" ng-show="isPage(1)">
    <div>
        text
    </div>
    <div myFocusDirective>
        <input>
    </div> 
</div>

<div id="page2" ng-show="isPage(2)">
    <div myFocusDirective>
        <button>
    </div>
</div>
```

I've been trying variations of a $watch on the attributes or using $timeout but I can't seem to accurately only match when ng-show is activated. My understanding is that it should just be applying "ng-hide" to and from the class of the div but I can't seem to match against that...

```
scope.$watch(function() { return element.attr('class'); }, function(newValue) {
    if (newValue.match(/ng-hide/g) === null && newValue.match(/highlight/g) === null && newValue.match(/complete/g) === null) {
         highlightAndFocus(element[0]);
    }
},true);
```

also tried using $timeout on the attrs but that's unreliable due to multiple matches because of classes being applied across divs.

```
scope.$watch(attr.initial, function(newValue) {
    $timeout(function() {
        highlightAndFocus(element[0]);
    });
},true);
```

Any help would be appreciated, I must be missing something here.

TLDR; After ng-show I want to modify the classes on a div and then focus on an input within the div

Comment: can you create a plunker, http://plnkr.co/edit

Answer (score 0):

Why not make your life easier for yourself and pass the contents of your ng-show to your div as well:

```
<div id="page2" ng-show="isPage(2)">
    <div myFocusDirective focuson="isPage(2)">
        <button>
    </div>
</div>
```

And watch the `focuson` in your directive scope?  This way, you don’t have to worry about parent classes, etc.

---

But in any case, if you are watching an `attr`, you should be using `attr.$observe`

Comment: So I'd put a $watch on this focuson attribute and if it becomes true then I can execute my desired javascript?

Comment: Yup!  That is what I would do.